# jQuery - What are the steps to create a plugin?

Tags: jquery, plugins

In an interview one candidate was asked "What are the steps to create a jQuery plugin?"
what is the most accurate or appropriate answer?

Comment: This question is a bit vague. Are you looking for code for your answer, or a listed, text breakdown of how a plugin is built?

Comment: @saesris - I was looking for a theoretical breakdown answer, if there is a code to this question which i agree is a little generic, most welcome for your answers.

Comment: Oh okay, that's how I answered it. Let me know if you need me to clarify anything in my answer below.

Comment: @saesris - I think you answered pretty much the right thing. One small query, since we are here trying to create a jquery plugin, what do you mean by saying first solve it in jquery, shorthand, shorthand?

Comment: By that I mean you write out in plain text what you're going to write in jQuery. For example, if I need a plugin that takes the value of filled in form items and then displays that text in an <h1> tag. In that case, item 2 in my list would include writing out something like the following:

Take the value from the form fields
Copy the value we get over into an <h1> tag

See, I'm just describing in plain text what I am about to do in jQuery code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your plugin on a `$.fn`

```
$.fn.greenify = function() {
    this.css( "color", "green" );
};
```

Then your plugin can be called by:

```
$( "a" ).greenify();
```

[Source](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)

Answer (score 1):

```
// https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/
$.fn.answer = function() { 
    return this.each(function() { 
        this.innerHTML = "Google is your friend - hint hint";
    }); 
};
$(document.body).answer();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the sort of question people ask to get you talking. There is no technically 'right' answer. There are some general rules, but again, you'd be best off just being honest about how you go about building a jQuery plugin. If you're honest, you'll accurately convey what you know, and an open-ended question like this will have served its purpose.

General Rules:

1. Start with a problem you need to solve.
2. Take some notes on how you would solve that problem in jQuery (essentially, in shorthand)
3. Write the code that you think will solve your problem.
4. Test the code in multiple different environments.
5. Debug the code as necessary.
6. You're done!